# Can't make raylib, receives makefile error 576: recipe for target 'rmodels.o' failed

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, raylib

I am trying to use MinGW to compile the raylib package, but it's not going very good. It gives me this error:

```
cc1.exe: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:576: recipe for target 'rmodels.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [rmodels.o] Error 1
```

This happens after i run:

```
mingw32-make PLATFORM=PLATFORM_DESKTOP
```

What am i doing wrong, what do i need to fix to make this work?

Comment: You haven't actually shown us the error.  The messages you show are just make telling you that some command failed.  To fix the problem you have to know what command failed and what errors it failed with.  Those will be shown _before_ the output you showed us.  When looking at build errors the most important ones are always the _first_ errors you see, not the last errors.  The line _some warnings being treated as errors_ means that, before the output you show us, there were some warnings, and the compiler treated them as errors, so failed.  Fix those warnings.

Comment: Can you tell us which version of raylib your trying to build with which version of MinGW or MinGW-w64 GCC? I can confirm raylib 4.0.0 builds fine with recent MinGW-w64 versions, in my case using cmake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the developer solved the case a couple of days ago. If you're sure that it's the right error, here is the link to the comment from the developers' GitHub:

https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/2137#issuecomment-968128325

He said it might be an issue with your current version of MinGW. There is a possibility that it's outdated.

Comment: Actually i had to make maybe 5-6 changes throughout the library to make it function with MinGW, and good thought i could upload my update of it to GiHub, but i don't know if my changes can screw up for other people, should i create my own fork, or what do you suggest i do?

Comment: @Falconeer Hmm... let's see, maybe you could try using vcpkg, cause that is way more efficient, if you're using Visual Studio 20XX. But if you're using VSCode, try re-installing the raylib repository on Github and update your MinGW using the link above I gave. For further questions, try asking the developer of raylib on Github, so they can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but for people with this problem in the future, I created a fork that fixed it for me. https://github.com/jamieengel011/raylib.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32316953)